# What's the best way to replace system files using python?

Tags: python, macos, popen, osx-mavericks

I've developed a developed a tiny tool to replace the Maverick Trash icon on the Dock by some pictures of MacPro: https://github.com/kxxoling/mavericktrash

I used os.popon() to run system commands:

```
sh = 'sudo cp %s %s' % (os.path.join(source, somefile), os.path.join(TRASH_PATH, somefile))
    os.popen(sh)
```

Is there any pythonicer way to do this?

Comment: http://amoffat.github.io/sh/

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html? 

Also, looking at your code on github, http://code.google.com/p/psutil/ might be a nice repalcement for your `killall`.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi This script is created for other users, but sh module needs to be downloaded, it's not very easy to use.

Comment: @PatrickCollins Seems shutils is what I need, many thanks!